# About the relation of the smell and costumers willing to buy (Neuromarketing Field)

Tags: correlation

I am trying to find some academic paper or the internet posts about **The effect of concentration and type of odor (irritating or relaxing) on the willingness of customers for buy**.

So I searched the above terms on the Google scholar and found the below results:

[The effect of concentration and type of odor (irritating or relaxing) on the willingness of customers for buy](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fa&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=The+effect+of+concentration+and+type+of+odor+%28irritating+or+relaxing%29+on+the+willingness+of+customers+for+buy&btnG=)

So, if possible, I am trying to find out, does the **higher level of fragrance** (odor) on the shopping place, **decrease the Buyer understands the price range**?

Thanks.

Comment: [Maureen Morrin](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Maureen+Morrin+scent&btnG=) has a number of publications about the effect of scent on consumer behavior; may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks **@Arnon_Weinberg**, your tags are useful, also the [effect of scent on consumer behavior](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=+effect+of+scent+on+consumer+behavior&btnG=) is useful for me.